# Elasticsearch How to do a OR query with wildcard

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am having a hard time trying to construct a query with elasticsearch.

I want to query something like:

```
WHERE field_1 is 'match' $string OR field_2 is 'wildcard_match' $string OR field_3 is 'fuzzy' $string
```

so what I tried to construct is something like this:

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "should" : [
            {
                "match" : { "field_1" : "testing" }
            },
            {
                "wildcard" : { "field_2" : "*testing*" }
            },
            {
                "fuzzy" : { "field_3" : "testing" }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1,
    }
}
```

But this seems to return an error.

Can anyone give a pointer how should I look into doing this kind of OR query with elasticsearch?

my current datasent:

```
{
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "tweet",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "field_1": "some data",
    "field_2": "testing data",
    "field_3": "other things"
  }
}
```

and my query:

```
curl -XGET  'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search' -d '
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "should" : [
            {
                "match" : { "field_1" : "testing" }
            },
            {
                "wildcard" : { "field_2" : "*testing*" }
            },
            {
                "fuzzy" : { "field_3" : "testing" }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1,
    }
}'
```

returns this error:

```
SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;
  shardFailures {[ZmwpcILwSEyufHf-t9xQ6g][twitter][0]:
  SearchParseException[[twitter][0]: from[-1],size[-1]:
    Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
      {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "field_1": "testing"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "field_2": "*testing*"
                }
              },
              {
                "fuzzy": {
                  "field_3": "testing"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
          }
        }
      }
    ]]]; 
  nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected START_OBJECT but got VALUE_STRING null]; }{[ZmwpcILwSEyufHf-t9xQ6g][twitter][1]: 
  SearchParseException[[twitter][1]: from[-1],size[-1]:
    Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
      {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "field_1": "testing"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "field_2": "*testing*"
                }
              },
              {
                "fuzzy": {
                  "field_3": "testing"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
          }
        }
      }
    ]]]; 
  nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected START_OBJECT but got VALUE_STRING null]; }{[ZmwpcILwSEyufHf-t9xQ6g][twitter][2]: 
  SearchParseException[[twitter][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "field_1": "testing"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "field_2": "*testing*"
              }
            },
            {
              "fuzzy": {
                "field_3": "testing"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
        }
      }
    }
  ]]]; 
  nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected START_OBJECT but got VALUE_STRING null]; }{[ZmwpcILwSEyufHf-t9xQ6g][twitter][3]: 
  SearchParseException[[twitter][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "field_1": "testing"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "field_2": "*testing*"
              }
            },
            {
              "fuzzy": {
                "field_3": "testing"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
        }
      }
    }
  ]]]; 
  nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected START_OBJECT but got VALUE_STRING null]; }{[ZmwpcILwSEyufHf-t9xQ6g][twitter][4]: 
  SearchParseException[[twitter][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "field_1": "testing"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "field_2": "*testing*"
              }
            },
            {
              "fuzzy": {
                "field_3": "testing"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
        }
      }
    }
  ]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected START_OBJECT but got VALUE_STRING null]; }]
```

Comment: What is the error that is returned?

Comment: @Jordan I have edited the question to include more info about my dataset and the error returned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to bad JSON format. 
The right JSON format for this query is as below -

```
{   // --->> This was missing
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field_1": "testing"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "field_2": "*testing*"
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "field_3": "testing"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}   // --->> This was missing
```