# Like query in ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

How to use a like query in a elasticsearch query?

this is what i have been trying so far.

```
array:3 [
"index" => "users"
"type" => "user"
"body" => array:1 [
"query" => array:1 [
  "bool" => array:1 [
    "should" => array:1 [
      0 => array:3 [
        0 => array:1 [
          "match" => array:1 [
            "fullname" => "Mag*"
          ]
        ]
        1 => array:1 [
          "match" => array:1 [
            "industry_name" => "other"
          ]
        ]
        2 => array:1 [
          "match" => array:1 [
            "active" => "yes"
           ]
         ]
       ]
     ]
     ]
     ]
   ]
   ]
```

My Search json is something like this,

```
{"1": "Mag","industry_name":"other", "active": "yes"}
```

In my indexes, there is a record for the full name "Maggie Wilfred".
when i run this query nothing gets returned.

any reason?.i feel the problem is in the wild card? `"fullname" => "Mag*"`

Comment: Actually that will depend.. If the query where statement is something like this `fullname="Mag*"` you'll get 0 result  but if it's the query statement is using LIKE you should be getting results coz it will get all fullname that starts `Mag`

Comment: @sgtBOSE: i have listed the query statements above

Comment: @DrixsonOseña: can you explain it bit.bit confused

Comment: @DamForums do you know how does `match` works?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña:`match` will act as `=` i think

Answer (score 1):

It should work, try it in this way:

```
    {
        "wildcard" : { "fullname" : "Mag*" }
    }
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: |: $match[] = array('wildcard' => array('fullname' => 'Mag*')); if i put like this it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The match query doesn't support wildcards as stated on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

You should try with the Wildcardquery.

Comment: according to this link says we can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670573/elasticsearch-how-to-do-a-or-query-with-wildcard

Comment: I don't see anything in this link that states that it works. In fact, the user has used three different types of queries, the first being a 100% match, the second being the wildcard match with leading and trailing *, and the last for fuzzy searching (when you mispell something).

Comment: what you are saying is that i cannot use wildcards and match in same query.is that right?

Comment: Yes, you have to use a different query than the match query if your terms need to be wildcard-friendly.

Comment: Can you give a better idea for that please?

Comment: Well, it depends on your usecase, but WildcardQueries can be a start, but it's commonly accepted that N-Gram filters give better performances and scale better. See : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "prefix" : { "fullname" : "Mag" }
}
```